# Calculate the correct OSRM route distance in OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers, distance, open-source-routing-machine

I extended this helpful fiddle by Jonatas Walker

https://jsfiddle.net/jonataswalker/079xha47/

by a route distance output. Here's the JS Code used:

```
var points = [],
  msg_el = document.getElementById('msg'),
  url_osrm_nearest = '//router.project-osrm.org/nearest/v1/driving/',
  url_osrm_route = '//router.project-osrm.org/route/v1/driving/',
  icon_url = '//cdn.rawgit.com/openlayers/ol3/master/examples/data/icon.png',
  vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector(),
  vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: vectorSource
  }),
  styles = {
    route: new ol.style.Style({
      stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
        width: 6,
        color: [40, 40, 40, 0.8]
      })
    }),
    icon: new ol.style.Style({
      image: new ol.style.Icon({
        anchor: [0.5, 1],
        src: icon_url
      })
    })
  };

console.clear();

var map = new ol.Map({
  target: 'map',
  layers: [
    new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: new ol.source.OSM()
    }),
    vectorLayer
  ],
  view: new ol.View({
    center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([12.47209, 51.34680]),
    zoom: 11
  })
});

map.on('click', function(evt) {
  utils.getNearest(evt.coordinate).then(function(coord_street) {
    var last_point = points[points.length - 1];
    var points_length = points.push(coord_street);

    utils.createFeature(coord_street);

    if (points_length < 2) {
      msg_el.innerHTML = 'Click to add another point';
      return;
    }

    //get the route
    var point1 = last_point.join();
    var point2 = coord_street.join();

    fetch(url_osrm_route + point1 + ';' + point2).then(function(r) {
      return r.json();
    }).then(function(json) {
      if (json.code !== 'Ok') {
        msg_el.innerHTML = 'No route found.';
        return;
      }
      msg_el.innerHTML = 'Route added';
      //points.length = 0;
      utils.createRoute(json.routes[0].geometry);
    });
  });
});

let fullLength = 0;

var utils = {
  getNearest: function(coord) {
    var coord4326 = utils.to4326(coord);
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      //make sure the coord is on street
      fetch(url_osrm_nearest + coord4326.join()).then(function(response) {
        // Convert to JSON
        return response.json();
      }).then(function(json) {
        if (json.code === 'Ok') resolve(json.waypoints[0].location);
        else reject();
      });
    });
  },
  createFeature: function(coord) {
    var feature = new ol.Feature({
      type: 'place',
      geometry: new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.fromLonLat(coord))
    });
    feature.setStyle(styles.icon);
    vectorSource.addFeature(feature);
  },
  createRoute: function(polyline) {
    // route is ol.geom.LineString
    var route = new ol.format.Polyline({
      factor: 1e5
    }).readGeometry(polyline, {
      dataProjection: 'EPSG:4326',
      featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857'
    });
    var feature = new ol.Feature({
      type: 'route',
      geometry: route
    });
    feature.setStyle(styles.route);
    vectorSource.addFeature(feature);
    fullLength += feature.getGeometry().getLength();
      
    if(fullLength > 100) document.getElementById('dist').innerHTML = Math.round((fullLength / 1000) * 100) / 100 + ' ' + 'km';
    else document.getElementById('dist').innerHTML = Math.round(fullLength * 100) / 100 + ' ' + 'm';
  },
  to4326: function(coord) {
    return ol.proj.transform([
      parseFloat(coord[0]), parseFloat(coord[1])
    ], 'EPSG:3857', 'EPSG:4326');
  }
};
```

See the [code inside this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/winnewoerp/zj31o0mu/17/)

Unfortunately, the returned distances are too large. I have a `LineString` feature in EPSG:3857 projection, thus "pseudo-metric", with distance distorting with growing distance to the equator. How do I need to change the following line to get a real metric distance?

```
fullLength += feature.getGeometry().getLength();
```

Comment: This is not nearly enough of relevant code to find the reason why distance is to large. Please edit your question and add all relevant existing code. And by the way, `feature.getGeometry().getLength()` gives length in units of the view projection. To get spherical length you have to use `ol.sphere.getLength()` function (see https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_sphere.html#.getLength).

Comment: You could also use `json.routes[0].distance` from OSRM

Comment: @TomazicM: Edited!

Comment: @Mike: Thank you, that works. Here's the new fiddle. But see my edit. What is the correct way to do it "inside" OpenLayers, for cases where the value isn't being delivered by an external API?

Comment: Sorry, fiddle link was missing: [Here's the new fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/winnewoerp/zj31o0mu/33/).

Comment: `ol.sphere.getLength(feature.getGeometry())` if the geometry is EPSG:3857. You will need OpenLayers 4 or laters to use that.

Comment: Q/A on GIS SE site are not intended only to solve problem of particular user, but be helpful resource for anybody with similar questions/problems. That's the reason question has to be complete in itself and include all relevant code, since outside links tend to get lost in time and also that there is no need to visit other sites to get complete picture of what the problem/question is. So please edit your question and add relevant existing code.

Comment: @TomazicM: See edited Q&A. I hope that it meets the requirements of "good GIS SA practice" now.

Comment: Yes, it's OK now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`feature.getGeomentry().getLength()` uses the units of the view projection (see [respective section of the OpenLayers 7 API Documentation](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_geom_LineString-LineString.html#getLength)), which is Web Mercator (EPSG:3857) in the provided example. To get the distance in meters, the route length needs to be calculated as spherical length (see [respective section of the OpenLayers 7 API Documentation](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_sphere.html#.getLength)) like so: `ol.sphere.getLength(feature.getGeometry())`.

Alternatively, the distance parameter provided by the OSRM API can be used (if no modifications of the provided route LineString are being done inside OpenLayers): `json.routes[0].distance` (see [this section of the OSRM API Documentation](http://project-osrm.org/docs/v5.5.1/api/#route-object)).

Here's a code example with a static route calculation, demonstrating the route calculation results:

```
// Preparing static route output for demonstration purposes
let points = [[12.44540,51.34617],[12.47915,51.34579]],
  url_osrm_route = '//router.project-osrm.org/route/v1/driving/',
  vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector(),
  vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: vectorSource
  });

let map = new ol.Map({
  target: 'map',
  layers: [
    new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: new ol.source.OSM()
    }),
    vectorLayer
  ],
  view: new ol.View({
    center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([12.47209, 51.34680]),
    zoom: 13
  })
});

fetch(url_osrm_route + points[0] + ';' + points[1]).then(function(r) {
    return r.json();
}).then(function(json) {
    if (json.code !== 'Ok') {
        return;
    }
  
  // Output first version of route length calculation (from OSRM API)
    document.getElementById('dist1').innerHTML = Math.round((json.routes[0].distance / 1000) * 10000) / 10000 + ' ' + 'km';

    utils.createRoute(json.routes[0].geometry);
  utils.createFeature(points[0]);
  utils.createFeature(points[1]);
});

let utils = {
  createFeature: function(coord) {
    let feature = new ol.Feature({
      type: 'place',
      geometry: new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.fromLonLat(coord))
    });
    vectorSource.addFeature(feature);
  },
  createRoute: function(polyline) {
        let route = new ol.format.Polyline({
      factor: 1e5
    }).readGeometry(polyline, {
      dataProjection: 'EPSG:4326',
      featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857'
    });
    let feature = new ol.Feature({
      type: 'route',
      geometry: route
    });
    vectorSource.addFeature(feature);
    
    // Output second version of route length calculation (on-the-fly calculation of spherical length)
    let routeLength2 = ol.sphere.getLength(feature.getGeometry());
    document.getElementById('dist2').innerHTML = Math.round((routeLength2 / 1000) * 10000) / 10000 + ' ' + 'km';
    
    // Output third ("wrong") version of route length calculation for comparison (distorted EPSG:3857)
    let routeLength3 = feature.getGeometry().getLength()
    document.getElementById('dist3').innerHTML = Math.round((routeLength3 / 1000) * 10000) / 10000 + ' ' + 'km';

  }
};
```

See this code inside the [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/winnewoerp/zj31o0mu/82/).

Comment: The purpose of GIS SE is to have Answers to Questions. If you hide the code from the Question *and* hide the code from the Answer, then when your code link fails, there is no value in either.

Comment: Best security practice is to not follow links. Having a more complete example in a link is fine, but if the *only* place your code exists is on another site, then the Q&A is at the mercy of another site. If others are to benefit, then the core code has to be inside the question.

Comment: Thanks for the hints. I edited (or "re-wrote") my answer. Hope this helps.